# Updating web.config revert previous updates

Tags: application-pages, web-config

I've a SPJob Scheduled with a package (wsp) installation which update web.config and a Application Page which also build to update web.config.

The problem is when I install the package it successfully update the web.config. I've confirmed the changes. Now, when we go to our Application Page which also successfully update the web.config but I lost the changes made during package installation.

Any idea what would I be doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be a clash of 'Owner' of the SPWebConfigModification? If both sets of code are using the same value, one could remove entries which were actually added by the other. A best practice is to use something tied to the class name for the 'Owner'.

Alternatively, are you *merging* the config changes in rather than adding nodes? If so, could something be going wrong there e.g. you're merging into the wrong place in the XML tree?

Comment: No, both sets of code are not using the same values. and we are not merging the web.config , we are adding the nodes.

Comment: I think you might need to post the code somehow for us to diagnose further..

Comment: // Add all modifications.
                foreach (ModificationEntry modEntry in _modifications)
                {
                    webApp.WebConfigModifications.Add(CreateModification(modEntry));
                }

                // Apply them via the farm's web service.
                webApp.WebService.ApplyWebConfigModifications();

Comment: Any Idea why that's happening

Answer (score 0):

How do you update the web.config?

The supported way to do it is by using the [SPWebConfigModification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spwebconfigmodification.aspx) classes

Comment: Yes i m modifying it with the SPwebConfigModification classes